# Oracle Multi-Table Insert Syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm taking my first look at Oracle's multi-table insert (I'm fairly new to SQL overall), and I'm not quite understanding the purpose/need for the `SELECT` at the end of the statement.

With a single-table `INSERT`, it's my understanding that either the `VALUES` clause or a subquery are used, but not both. Can someone explain the significance of the `SELECT` clause at the end of this `INSERT` statement? I've looked online, but I haven't found a clear answer.

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN prod_category='B' THEN
INTO book_sales(prod_id,cust_id,qty_sold,amt_sold)
VALUES(product_id,customer_id,sale_qty,sale_price)
WHEN prod_category='V' THEN
INTO video_sales(prod_id,cust_id,qty_sold,amt_sold)
VALUES(product_id,customer_id,sale_qty,sale_price)
WHEN prod_category='A' THEN
INTO audio_sales(prod_id,cust_id,qty_sold,amt_sold)
VALUES(product_id,customer_id,sale_qty,sale_price)
SELECT prod_category ,product_id ,customer_id ,sale_qty, sale_price
FROM sales_detail;
```

Comment: read the select first:  select x,y from table1.  For each row, when x='Foo', insert into table2, when x='Bar', then insert into table3, etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select is used to determine the values of the variable **prod_category** used in `WHEN prod_category='B' THEN`